# How to get the most recent event per date in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a table of the form:

| eventType | date | userId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| login | 2022-01-01 | bob |
| login | 2022-01-02 | bob |
| login | 2022-01-02 | alice |
| login | 2022-01-05 | alice |
| subscribe | 2022-01-07 | alice |
| login | 2022-01-09 | alice |
| ... | ... | ... |

I'm looking to create a table of the form

| asOfDate | userId | eventType | mostRecentEventDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | alice | login | NULL |
| 2022-01-01 | bob | login | 2022-01-01 |
| 2022-01-02 | alice | login | 2022-01-02 |
| 2022-01-02 | bob | login | 2022-01-02 |
| 2022-01-03 | alice | login | 2022-01-02 |
| 2022-01-03 | bob | login | 2022-01-02 |
| 2022-01-04 | alice | login | 2022-01-02 |
| 2022-01-04 | bob | login | 2022-01-02 |
| 2022-01-05 | alice | login | 2022-01-05 |
| 2022-01-05 | bob | login | 2022-01-02 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Where `asOfDate` is consecutive calendar days, and `mostRecentEventDate` gives you the date of the most recent event of type `eventType` and for user `userId`.

To illustrate the idea, if I run

```
SELECT mostRecentEventDate 
FROM new_table 
WHERE userId = 'alice'
AND eventType = 'login' 
AND asOfDate = '2022-02-04'
```

I want to get the date of alice's most recent login before 2022-02-04

### Edit:

This code works, it is just not very performant:

```
WITH all_combinations AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM date_range --A table with all calendar dates labelled asOfDate
    CROSS JOIN user_events
    WHERE date <= asOfDate
)

SELECT 
    *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        PARTITION BY userId, eventType ORDER BY date DESC
    ) AS recency_index
FROM all_combinations 
    WHERE recency_index = 1
```

Comment: Not clear. Fill in some representative sample data and the desired result.

Comment: You'll need some sort of calendar table to join to your data table.

Comment: I have one, call it `date_range`

Comment: Use a cursor to loop in your "date_range" table and, for each date, insert a new record on a droped and created temp table (or clear records of existing table). Then use your script on this "temp_table".